# How can i remove infinite water sources?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So when my friend tried to build with water he accedentaly messed up somehow. I am playing on a server so i cant use any mods or plugins or anything. The game i am playing on the server is creative so i have a limited space to build. Anyways I want to know a way to clear all of this water out without worldedit in a easy way that is also quick. I want a way to clear all of this water. Thanks!

[image: The water source]

Comment: Displace it with sand.

Answer (score 1):

You can pour buckets of lava to flow onto the water until all the water turns to cobblestone